# inputType = "number|text" not working - Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

I am using `inputType = "number|text"` inside `TextInputEditText` when I focus on this, It lets me type number only, It allows to navigate to text keyboard but not letting me type text.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/availableRoof"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radio_groupPcOfInstltion"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/avlbleRoofTextField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Available Roof/Ground Area(sq.ft.)"
        android:inputType="number|text"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="13sp" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Please suggest a solution, so that I can type text and number both.

Comment: use `android:inputType="text" 
  android:digits="0123456789qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm_-"`

Comment: use `android:inputType="text"` and you will be able to enter numbers as well.

Comment: @HemantParmar Nice suggestion sir, Helped me to solve the issue.

Comment: @AndroidDev welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Just use input type `text` for getting the all possible options and `textVisiblePassword` for removing the suggestion and show number in one keyboard.

```
android:inputType="text"
```

OR

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

Comment: Be careful with `textVisiblePassword`, it may launch "Do you want to store this password in Google?" dialog. Happening i.e. on Pixel 6, Android 12. For non-credentials and insensitive information, `inputType="text"` is better option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the inputType as text, so that you can easily enter text as well as numbers in the TextInputEditText.

Use: `android:inputType="text"`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these properties:

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```